# Query Concatenation

Tags: php, query, mysql, errors

I can't figure out how to properly concatenate my PHP variables in my MySQL query.

**$convert_class_id** and **$convert_char_id** are holding numerical values.

When I try to activate my plugin I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'

```
$skill_select = $wpdb->get_results(
                    $wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT skill_name, char_id, um_id, c.class_id
                FROM `wp_ml_skill_class` sc
                JOIN `wp_ml_skill` s ON (s.skill_id = sc.skill_id)
                JOIN `wp_ml_character` c
                WHERE c.class_id = " . $convert_class_id . " " AND c.char_id = " " . $convert_char_id . "
                "));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL statement use placeholders instead of variable: `%s` (string) or `%d` (number). 
The second argument of `prepare()` is array of variables to substitute into the placeholders.

```
$skill_select = $wpdb->get_results(
                $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT skill_name, char_id, um_id, c.class_id
            FROM `wp_ml_skill_class` sc
            JOIN `wp_ml_skill` s ON (s.skill_id = sc.skill_id)
            JOIN `wp_ml_character` c
            WHERE c.class_id = %d AND c.char_id = %d",
            [$convert_class_id, $convert_char_id]));
```

Comment: Ok, my query works as intended. Thanks for that. I thought those were SQL wildcards, but I researched what you said and found out that they're PHP string functions. http://php.net/sprintf